# During Ant build Adobe Flex 3 shell script getting killed even within RAM limits

Tags: shell, apache-flex, ant

```
run-fcsh:
 [exec] Adobe Flex Compiler SHell (fcsh)
 [exec] Version 3.0.0 build 477
 [exec] Copyright (c) 2004-2007 Adobe Systems, Inc. All rights reserved.
 [exec]
 [exec] (fcsh) fcsh: Assigned 1 as the compile target id
 [exec] Loading configuration file /home/localhost/flex_3_sdk/frameworks/flex-config.xml
 [exec] /home/localhost/trunk/kavalok-build/bin/flash/localization.swc (35419 bytes)
 [exec] (fcsh) (fcsh) fcsh: Assigned 2 as the compile target id
 [exec] Loading configuration file /home/localhost/flex_3_sdk/frameworks/flex-config.xml
Killed
```

I'm trying to build my Ant files, and whenever I try to run to this part, Ant gets killed. So I went to the source code and reduced the max RAM to 64MB. (My VPS has 256MB RAM.) This does not work, and the exact same thing happens. What should I do from here and how can I reduce the RAM of everything so it runs smoothly and without being killed?

Answer (score 0):

In the Eclipse settings give more RAM to the Java VM:

Set `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > select current > edit > VM arguments`
to `-Xms512m -Xmx1024m`

This needs to be done for your current Java version, so if you update Java you will need to do this again.